# preventing duplicate transactions in authorize.net using x_duplicate_window

Tags: authorize.net

I do not see this question on this site but if it has been answered please direct me to the answer. According to authorize.net you can help prevent duplicate transactions using x_duplicate_window.

Can anyone tell me what file I would put that in and what that would look like? i can't find anything in the civicrm documentation.

Thanks